# Exception Description: A descriptor with default root element project was not found in the project]

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I'm trying to unmarshall this file xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
  <database password="" url="" username=""/>
  <entities>
    <entity name="" table=""/>
  </entities>
  <controllers>
    <controller entity="">
      <methods>
        <method name=""/>
      </methods>
    </controller>
  </controllers>
</project>
```

with this code:

```
JAXBContext jc = org.eclipse.persistence.
                    jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(new Class[] { Project.class },
                    null);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
            File xml = new File(FileSystem.getConfigurationPath());
            Project o = (Project) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);
```

The class Project is:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "database",
    "entities",
    "controllers"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "project")
public class Project {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected Project.Database database;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected Project.Entities entities;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected Project.Controllers controllers;
    ...
```

but I got the following error:

jakarta.xml.bind.UnmarshalException

- with linked exception:
  [Exception [EclipseLink-25008] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 3.0.0.v202012081010): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
  Exception Description: A descriptor with default root element project was not found in the project]
  at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.handleXMLMarshalException(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:1136)
  at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:149)

Could you help me to understand why?

Many Thanks.